# Firebase Dynamic Links Not Working on Apple iMessage (Flutter)

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dynamic-linking, imessage

I have implemented dynamic links into a flutter app I am working on. They are working as expected on everything I have tested EXCEPT iMessage. What is odd is if I copy and paste the link from the share popup, the message appears and send correctly. However, if I share it directly to iMessage (without the copy/paste step) the text preview is fine, but when it send it only shows the long link and not any of the preview meta data.

Link Generation:

```
class DynamicLinkService {
Future<Uri> createDynamicLink(String navPage, String id) async {
    final DynamicLinkParameters parameters = DynamicLinkParameters(
      uriPrefix: 'https://example.page.link',
      link: Uri.parse('https://example.com/?navPage=$navPage&id=$id'),
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: 'com.example.example',
        minimumVersion: 1,
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: 'com.example.example',
        minimumVersion: '1',
        appStoreId: '12345678',
      ),
    );
    var dynamicUrl = await parameters.buildShortLink();
    final Uri shortUrl = dynamicUrl.shortUrl;
    return shortUrl;
}
```

On press link generation:

```
class _FeedPageWidgetState extends State<FeedPageWidget>
  final DynamicLinkService _dynamicLinkService = DynamicLinkService();

Align(
alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
child: FlutterFlowIconButton(                                 
 icon: Icon(),
    onPressed: () async {
    var uri = await _dynamicLinkService
    .createDynamicLink('param 1', 'param 2');
    await Share.share(uri.toString());
    print(uri.toString());
    },
  ),
),
```

Below are some image examples of what I am seeing:
Image preview selecting iMessage directly from the share popup.

[image]

Image of link after sending. Notice it only shows the full dynamic link.

[image]

Image showing copying and pasting the dynamic link from the share pop-up. Notice how it sends correctly in this manner.

[image]

Any help on this?

Comment: I have this same issue... Sharing via WhatsApp or just copying works fine, so what is going on with iMessage...

Comment: @James the only way I could find to fix this was adding some text before the link. If there is also a text message being sent, then the link preview works fine. Not really sure why though.